# Android java : Returns method from another project

Tags: java, android, project

I am trying to call method from a java project to a android project
but it returns wrong value let me put an example:

lets say in java project i do this:

> ```
> value = false; if(Something.equals(something){ value = true; }
> ```

```
public static boolean getValue() {

    return value;

}
```

in the java project it returns true;

but when i do

```
JavaProject.getValue()
```

on android project it returns false:

Why does this happens?

Comment: debug your code, add breakpoint to verify "Is your IF condition altering value's value or not?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Check your import statement of that class. You might have imported incorrect Java file.

2.Secondly check your `if(Something.equals(something){ value = true; }` condition is executed, as it is making the variable true.

Comment: is `if(Something.equals(something){ value = true; }` getting executed ? I am sure it's not..

Comment: Yes it does.                                                               if (getArrayListString().contains("PRESSED")) {
     System.out.println("ARRAYLIST CONTAINS PRESSED...");
     value = true
    }

Comment: Now check if getArrayListString() contains "PRESSED"...print those values before if condition and remember `contains` method is case sensative..

Comment: Yes it prints true on java project but in android project still prints "false"...

Comment: That means when you are running from android, getArrayListString() does not contain `PROCESSED`

Comment: Debug and Check why getArrayListString() is not returning with PROCESSED

Comment: It just keeps return false even if i'm setting it to true with no if statements...